# Change cam constraint deviceId of mediaStream

Tags: javascript, stream, camera, constraints, getusermedia

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
</head>
<body>
<video autoplay muted id="lh"></video>
<!--RCA type-->
<select id="y"></select>
<select id="rw"></select>

<script>
"use strict";
try {
    navigator.wakeLock.request("screen");
    const y = document.getElementById('y'),
        rw = document.getElementById('rw'),
        p1 = document.getElementById('lh');
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(a => {
        a.forEach(b => {
            let c = `<option value="${b.deviceId}">${b.label}</option>`;
            b.kind == 'videoinput' ? y.innerHTML += c : rw.innerHTML += c
        });
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            audio: 1,
            video: 1
        }).then(e => {
            p1.srcObject = e;
            p1.onloadedmetadata = () => p1.play();
            y.onchange = () => {
                e.getVideoTracks()[0].applyConstraints({
                    video: {
                        deviceId: y.value
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    })
} catch (e) {
    alert(e)
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Live demo URL](https://abhi-inter.000webhostapp.com/WebRTC/local.html)

I want to allow user to change the cam. But it is not changing. I am unable to trace the exact issue. The value of the `select` tag is also being changed to `deviceId` of cam that user chooses successfully. The `onchange` event is also firing. Kindly help me.

[Present Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ebDW.jpg)